# Regex not passing the check

Tags: javascript, regex

The following statement when `provider[x].prefixRegExp = /^5[1-5]/` and `val = 55` doesn't return true... am I doing something wrong?

```
if (provider[x].prefixRegExp.test(val)) {
     $('#payment-panel .credit-card-type .'+provider[x].name).addClass('selected').attr('rel', x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^5[1-5]/.test(55)` actually *does* return true. Make sure that `provider[x].prefixRegExp` and `val` are as you expected by adding `alert(provider[x].prefixRegExp + ' ' + val);` before those lines and `alert("it is true, your css or jquery selector is broken");` in the if condition.

Comment: Or use console.log instead of alert if you are using firebug or similar.  It's a bit easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked in browser console:

```
>> /^5[1-5]/.test("55")
<< true
```

So looks like your `val` not equals `55` or your `provider[x].prefixRegExp` not the `/^5[1-5]/`